# Setting initial conditions of a domain grid?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule, cellular-automata

So I'm writing some code to try and produce a cellular automaton which will model an oscillatory chemical reaction, but I'm trying to set up the initial conditions of the grid so that I can vary them to see how they change the behavior.

Basically my method has been to use Table to generate a series of nested lists which give the x and y coordinates of the bottom left corner of a grid square, and also attached to those coordinates is a value which can run from 0 to some integer - it is this number that I will be updating to make the automaton evolve. So I essentially have a list that looks like;

```
{{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{2,0,0}...{0,3,0},{1,3,0}...{n,n,0}}
```

But what I want to do is to specify a list of initial conditions, so that the initial domain might look something more like;

```
{{0,0,7},{1,0,3}...{2,3,9},{3,3,0},{4,3,2}...{n,n,3}}
```

Just for argument's sake.

I've tried a few different ways of doing this - using replacement rules and whatnot, but none of it has worked. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two more ways.

```
lst = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}};
init = {7, 3, 9};
MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2} &, {lst, init}]
```

and

```
helper[{a_, b_}, c_] := {a, b, c}
Thread[helper[lst, init]]
```

Both produce

`{{0, 0, 7}, {1, 0, 3}, {2, 0, 9}}`

P.S. Just for fun and as my entry into this month's obfuscated *Mathematica* contest:

```
Inner[Append, Hold @@ lst, Hold @@ init, List]
```

Comment: I like "...obfuscated Mathematica contest..."  : `Append @@@ Transpose[{st, init}]` is my entry (late comer handicap though)...apolpgies if it is already somewhere

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.  For instance,

```
lst = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}};
init = {7, 3, 9};
MapThread[Append[#1, #2] &, {lst, init}]
(* {{0, 0, 7}, {1, 0, 3}, {2, 0, 9}} *)
```

or

```
lst1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}};
MapThread[ReplacePart[#1, 3 -> #2] &, {lst1, init}]
```

which produces the same result.  See [Adding, Removing, and Modifying List Elements](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AddingRemovingAndModifyingListElements.html) for a discussion of this topic.